# Peewee and Updates

Tags: python, peewee

How do I know if a record was in fact updated?  Here is my code:

```
for team, rating in team_ratings.items():
      query1 = Ratings.update(sagarin_rating=rating).where(Ratings.sagarin_name == team)
      query1.execute()
```

Lets say though that I don't actually have a `sagarin_name` that equals `team`.  Is there any way to see if 0 rows were updated.  I see on the Peewee doc page, that doing updates right into IDLE returns the rows that were updated.  But how can I capture if any rows updated into a variable?

I need to be able to test if the record was updated or not.  Using sqlite with Peewee.

Answer (score 2):

peewee update query by default returns count of no of results updated, store the output of execute statement and use it following statements as needed

```
for team, rating in team_ratings.items():
      query1 = Ratings.update(sagarin_rating=rating).where(Ratings.sagarin_name == team)
      no_of_row_updated = query1.execute()
      print no_of_row_updated
```